# Ajax submission to update backing bean property in jsf 1.2

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using jsf 1.2 with rich faces library

I have a form like this :

```
<a4j:form>

    <!-- lof of other components here -->
    <h:panelGrid>

        <h:inputText id="someOrg" value="#{someBean.Data}">
        <a4j:commandButton id=""action="${someOtherBean.processData}" value="Submit"> <!-- it can be a4j:commandButton too-->
    </h:panelGrid>


    <!-- some components will be rendered based on above submission -->

</a4j:form>
```

As shown in above form , I want to submit h:inputText with ajax to server using button.
Only PART inside  should be processed.

My question is I want to access someBean.Data from someOtherBean.processData method with ajax.How can I achieve that ?

I tried folllowing things but no success.

1)Use 4j:commandButton and use ajaxSingle="true" , since only certain portion needs to be submitted.(if I submit whole 
form validation erros will be thrown)

2)Used h:commandButton with a4j:support

3)Enclose necesary components inside  , using this will submit only selected region to server.

In all the above cases , form gets submitted but someBean.Data always returns null.

Comment: inputText component not closed. Check this once.

Answer (score 1):

If Bean1 is request scoped you can get current instance of that that bean using

```
Bean1 bean =(Bean1) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("bean1");
```

if bean is session scoped then

```
Bean1 bean = (Bean1) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap().get("bean1");
```

You can write above code in your `processData` method

For more information about communication between managed beans go through [this](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) link